# R: Multiply value X by 1st row in column Y, next multiply result Z by 2nd row column Y

Tags: r, loops, matrix

My DF is composed of 1 variable "Return" length=131, and I have separate object "TP"

```
TP <- 87
print(DF)
Return
0.0904
0.0312
0.0005
-0.0225
....
```

I am struggling to find the correct code to do the following:

```
create a new column vector "NewVec" where: 
R1= (0.0904+1)*TP
R2= (0.0312+1)*R1
R3= (0.0005+1)*R3
```

Currently I have only managed to multiply the entire Return vector by TP

```
NewVec <- (Return+1)*TP
```

Clearly this does not produce the desired result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a shot in the dark.

```
newvec<-matrix(nrow=length(Return))
for(i in 1:length(Return)){
  if(i==1)newvec[i,]<-(Return[i]+1)*TP
  else newvec[i,]<-(Return[i]+1)*newvec[i-1,]
}
```

Comment: Looks good. I was hoping to find a shorter and vectorized solution but this seems to do the trick. Maybe you could replace `Return` with `DF`, which is the name of the data.frame according to the OP.